# HTTP client PUT request error

Tags: java, apache, http

I am making a PUT request using apache HTTP client in java but i am getting some error. here is my function for that :

```
public static void putRequest(String url, JSONObject setObject)
    {
       try
       {
          PutMethod put = new PutMethod(url);
          HttpMethodParams httpParams = new HttpMethodParams();
            if( setObject != null)
                  httpParams.setParameter("JSONString", setObject.toJSONString());

                   put.setParams(httpParams);
                   try
                   {
                       int result = httpclient.executeMethod(put);
                       System.out.println("HTTP response code : " + result);
                       String getResp = put.getResponseBodyAsString();
                       System.out.println("postresp  ==> " + getResp);
                       put.releaseConnection();
                   }
                   catch(Exception e)
                   {
                       e.printStackTrace();
                   }
       }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
                       e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

and the response i am getting is :

```
{"code":6,"message":"Internal Error"}
```

Where i am doing wrong?

Comment: Your error comes from endpoint url. Probably, you are providing wrong data, and it gives error on backend

Answer (score 0):

This seems to be the response from the server. (I guess the actual output is `postresp  ==> {"code":6,"message":"Internal Error"}`)

It is not an error in your code, but an internal error at the server side. You should check the server code/logs/contact the admin.